# Rust warp redirect removing some headers

Tags: redirect, networking, rust, reverse-proxy, rust-warp

I'm trying to redirect requests to some URL. My server is using rust with warp.

The library https://docs.rs/warp-reverse-proxy/latest/warp_reverse_proxy/ seems to do exactly what I need, but when it redirects with all the headers the server receiving the request rejects it for 2 reasons:

- the host header isn't what it expects
- the content-length isn't what it expects

I tried removing those headers but I can't make the filters work. I tried so many combinations that pasting all of them here won't be very helpful.

Is there a preferred way of capturing a request, removing some headers and then redirect it?

Edit to add some code:

```
    warp::serve(
        warp::get()
            .and(warp::path("graphiql"))
            .and(juniper_warp::graphiql_filter("/graphql", None))
            .or(warp::path("graphql").and(graphql_filter))
            // .or(reverse_proxy_filter(
            //     "".to_string(),
            //     "https://example.com/".to_string(),
            // ))
            .with(log),
    )
    .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080))
    .await
```

`user` -> `proxy.com` -> `example.com`

The reverse_proxy_filter redirects, but the Host on the other side rejects the call. These are in different domains. So when `example.com` receives the request it rejects it because the `Host` header has the original domain.

Edit: Solved by adding another filter:

```rust
.or(warp::any().and(request_filter).and_then(
    |path, query, method, mut headers: Headers, body: Body| {
        headers.remove("Host");
        headers.remove("Content-length");

        proxy_to_and_forward_response(
            "https://example.com".to_string(),
            "".to_string(),
            path,
            query,
            method,
            headers,
            body,
        )
    },
))
```

Comment: What host is it sending and what does the target server expect? What content-length is it sending and what does the target server expect? Flat out omitting those headers is unlikely to help.

Comment: The Host that the server expects is itself. So if the original request goes to example.com and then I redirect it to other.com, this last server expects other.com as Host.
The content-length has me a little more intrigued, but when doing some tests with curl turns out that was the problem.